# Max/min/count etc. not giving good value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a f1 `database` from `ergast.com`. I've tried to get best `laptime` and number of `pitstops` for each driver in each race, so I've written sql query like this:

```
SELECT results.driverId, results.constructorId, races.circuitId, races."year"-1949,
       results.statusId, results.positionOrder, results.grid, results.points, 
       results.laps, ISNULL(max(pitstops.stop), 0), min(laptimes.milliseconds), 
       results.fastestLapTime, drivers.forename, drivers.surname, circuits.name
FROM results 
INNER JOIN races 
   ON (results.raceId = races.raceId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN pitstops 
   ON (races.raceId = pitstops.raceId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN laptimes 
   ON (laptimes.raceId = races.raceId)
INNER JOIN drivers 
   ON (drivers.driverId = results.driverId)
INNER JOIN circuits 
   ON (circuits.circuitId = races.circuitId)
WHERE ((races."year"=2011) OR (races."year"=2012))
  AND ((races.circuitId = 1) OR (races.circuitId = 2))
GROUP BY results.driverId, constructorId, races.circuitId, races."year"-1949,
         statusId, positionOrder, grid, points, laps, fastestLapTime, forename,
         surname, circuits.name
```

Unfortunately this gives me the same best `laptime` and number of `pitstops` for every driver in given race. How can I fix it? Should I add something to `group by`?

Comment: Because you're grouping by `fastestLapTime`, no?

Comment: you can change your or statements with in right? YEAR in(2011, 2012) and circuitid in (1, 2) ?

Comment: Could you please add a Qualifier to all columns. E.g.: Is `fastestLapTime` from table `laptimes`? Then `laptimes.fastestLapTime`. etc.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Done

Comment: @IvanStarostin I've added it to check results, deleting it doesn't change the results unfortunately

Comment: Analyze your group by. What is in the same group? Do you want to find the fastest driver of a race, or circuit or year or whatever? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining pitstops on raceId only, thus getting the maximum pitstop per race. But you say "and number of pitstops for every driver in given race". This indicates that a pitstop should be related to a driver, e.g.:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN pitstops 
   ON (results.raceId = pitstops.raceId and results.driverId = pitstops.driverId)
```

The same should be true for laptimes.

(There may be more errors in your query. Please qualify all columns with a table name, if you want more help, so we see which columns is in which table. Even better would be table definitions.)

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem, I didnt know that you can join tables by two sets of columns at once

Comment: Yes that is essential. You must join the tables on all relevant columns. Otherwise you get duplicates and combinations you don't want. Your join for example combined every pitstop with every driver that happened to be in the same race.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer already given: You can simplify your query by getting the aggregates in subqueries (either in the `FROM` clause or in the `SELECT` clause). E.g.:

```
select 
  results.driverid,
  results.constructorid,
  races.circuitid,
  races."year" - 1949,
  results.statusid,
  results.positionorder,
  results.grid,
  results.points,
  results.laps,
  (
    select coalesce(max(stop), 0)
    from pitstops
    where pitstops.raceid = results.raceid
    and pitstops.driverid = results.driverid
  ) as max_pitstops,
  (
    select coalesce(min(milliseconds), 0)
    from laptimes
    where laptimes.raceid = results.raceid
    and laptimes.driverid = results.driverid
  ) as min_laptimes,
  results.fastestlaptime,
  drivers.forename,
  drivers.surname,
  circuits.name
from results
join drivers on drivers.driverid = results.driverid
join races on races.raceid = results.raceid
join circuits on circuits.circuitid = races.circuitid
where races."year" in (2011, 2012)
and races.circuitid in (1, 2);
```

or

```
select 
  results.driverid,
  results.constructorid,
  races.circuitid,
  races."year" - 1949,
  results.statusid,
  results.positionorder,
  results.grid,
  results.points,
  results.laps,
  coalesce(pits.max_stop, 0) as max_pitstops,
  coalesce(laps.min_milliseconds, 0) as min_laptimes,
  results.fastestlaptime,
  drivers.forename,
  drivers.surname,
  circuits.name
from results
join drivers on drivers.driverid = results.driverid
join races on races.raceid = results.raceid
join circuits on circuits.circuitid = races.circuitid
left join
(
  select raceid, driverid, max(stop) as max_stop
  from pitstops
  group by raceid, driverid
) pits on pits.raceid = results.raceid and pits.driverid = results.driverid
left join
(
  select raceid, driverid, min(milliseconds) as min_milliseconds
  from laptimes
  group by raceid, driverid
) laps on laps.raceid = results.raceid and laps.driverid = results.driverid
where races."year" in (2011, 2012)
and races.circuitid in (1, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is yet another "answer" :-)

You are using technical IDs (raceId, driverId, etc.) and you are surprised you have to join on more than one column. This indeed is somewhat untypical for a database that is based on technical IDs. So let's check why this is...

There should be a table that lists the drivers per race. Let's call it `participation`:

```
participation(participationid, raceid, driverid)
```

With such a table, your other tables would no longer contain the combination of `raceid` and `driverid`, but only the `participationid`:

```
pitstops(pitstopid, participationid, stop, ...)

laptimes(laptimeid, participationid, milliseconds, ...)

results(resultid, participationid, points, ...)
```

And you'd join accordingly on that one column only:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN pitstops 
  ON pitstops.participationid = results.participationid
```

I take it, however, that there can be just one result record per `raceid` and `driverid`? Then your participation table is the results table really (only with a worse name :-). You should hence have a resultid in the table and the other tables referring to it:

```
pitstops(pitstopid, resultid, stop, ...)

laptimes(laptimeid, resultid, milliseconds, ...)
```

And you'd join accordingly on that one column only:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN pitstops 
  ON pitstops.resultid = results.resultid
```